# While working on our app theme extension we noticed preorder payment button not displaying, how to fix this?

Tags: node.js, shopify

We updated our shopify app to app bridge 3 and are using the Shopify CLI however while working on our app theme extension we noticed the payment option was not connecting to the product and the payment button was not displaying, is there a solution to this?

this is what it looks like

[image: 1]

this is what it needs to be

[image: 2]

Comment: There's a problem (probably a syntax error) in your liquid code. That's why you get JSON encoding output on the product page. Double check your liquid code (product template) or share it here.

Comment: Hi Genevieve, thanks for your response.  It appears we have limited space in this comment section but here's a google doc link to share here so you can see: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1grGuoxg4ILMLqtpAN9T-CSwblkNKDuXo0SdgwdOf0do/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I added the json output on purpose and now I have removed it, but the button is not showing